# Unable to remove a DOM element using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am unable to remove an `hr` element in javascript. Here is what I've tried:

```
var hr = document.getElementsByTagName("hr");
hr.parentNode.removeChild(hr);
```

It says

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'removeChild' of undefined

Although an `[<hr>]` is being returned by the first line. I then checked `console.log(hr.parentNode)` and it says undefined.

Can anyone please tell me why is that, why is it not accessing the `parentNode` of `hr` and in turn not removing the element?

Comment: @Praveen Not a choice.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: why? There's no need for it.

Comment: Probably, (s)he was going to suggest `$("hr").remove()`.

Comment: @KamranAhmed **She**???

Comment: This should be marked as duplicate. There is at least 10 Qs with similar name and explanation of root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList` which is an array-like object that contains all the `hr` in the page. You need to loop through it, like an array to access each one in the set.

```
var hr = document.getElementsByTagName("hr");
for (var i = 0; i < hr.length; i++) {
  hr[i].parentNode.removeChild(hr);
}
```

Comment: Nit: It's get [element*s*ByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName). The original post contains a few errors.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. I should blame the guy who invented "copy-paste" for this. :D

Answer (score 1):

You should to try this code in the following exemple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="removeElement()">RemoveElement</button>
    <hr />
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">     

        function removeElement() {
            var hr = document.getElementsByTagName("hr");
            hr[0].parentNode.removeChild(hr[0]);
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```